Append Filename to File in Azure Storage
I am a bit stuck in a simple problem but I seem to have lost grey matter and keep looping (which is exactly a problem here). I am trying to upload the files from local to azure storage and then append the file name to the file in the cloud so later I can add and check if I have already processed such file.
Here is my code:
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient,DataLakeFileClient





    # Iterate over files in the local directory
    for filename in os.listdir(local_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(local_path, filename)):
            # Get a reference to the file client
            file_client = directory_client.get_file_client(filename)

            # Upload the file to Azure Data Lake Storage
            with open(os.path.join(local_path, filename), "rb") as local_file:
                file_client.upload_data(local_file, overwrite=True)

            if not checkpoint_directory_client.create_file(file=checkpoint_file_name):
                checkpoint_directory_client.create_file(file=checkpoint_file_name)
                checkpoint_file_client = checkpoint_directory_client.get_file_client(checkpoint_file_name)
                
             *<<<I think I need something here but I tried everything and I cannot seem to do it>>>>*

I tried with DataLakeFileClient as well but to no avail. I either can upload one name to the file (last one which is indicative of the position inside a loop)or get empty file. I just need a little push in the right direction!
I am trying something like this
checkpoint_directory_client.create_file(file=checkpoint_file_name)
checkpoint_file_client = checkpoint_directory_client.get_file_client(checkpoint_file_name)
data = filename
checkpoint_file_client.append_data(data,offset=0,length=len(data))
checkpoint_file_client.flush_data(len(data))

Thanks a bunch


Append Filename to File in Azure Storage

You can use the code below to append the filename to the file after creating the checkpoint file, using the append_data method of the DataLakeFileClient object.
Here is the full code:
Code:
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient, DataLakeFileClient

try:
    account_url = "https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/"
    default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url, credential=default_credential)
    container_name = "test"
    directory_name = "sample"
    filesystem_name = container_name
    directory_name = directory_name
    checkpoint_directory_name = "checkpoint"
    checkpoint_file_name = "checkpointfile.txt"

    local_path = r"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\venkat1"
    if not os.path.exists(local_path):
        os.mkdir(local_path)
    directory_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(filesystem_name).get_directory_client(directory_name)
    checkpoint_directory_client = service_client.get_directory_client(file_system=filesystem_name, directory=f"{directory_name}/{checkpoint_directory_name}")
    checkpoint_file_client = checkpoint_directory_client.get_file_client(checkpoint_file_name)
    checkpoint_file_service = DataLakeFileClient(account_url=account_url, credential=default_credential, file_system_name=filesystem_name, file_path=checkpoint_file_client.path_name)

    # Iterate over files in the local directory
    for filename in os.listdir(local_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(local_path, filename)):
            file_client = directory_client.get_file_client(filename)
            with open(os.path.join(local_path, filename), "rb") as local_file:
                file_client.upload_data(local_file, overwrite=True)

            checkpoint_directory_client.create_file(file=checkpoint_file_name)
            checkpoint_file_client = checkpoint_directory_client.get_file_client(checkpoint_file_name)
            data = filename.encode('utf-8')
            checkpoint_file_client.append_data(data, offset=0, length=len(data))
            checkpoint_file_client.flush_data(len(data))

    print("All files uploaded successfully.")

except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)

The above code uploads files from a local directory to Azure Data Lake Storage and creates a checkpoint file to keep track of the uploaded files. For each file, it appends the filename to the checkpoint file using the append_data method of the DataLakeFileClient object.
Output:
All files uploaded successfully.


Portal:

Reference:
Use Python to manage data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
Update:
To write the all files into the (checkpoint)file you can modify code as like below:
Code:
for filename in os.listdir(local_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(local_path, filename)):
            file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            new_filename = f"{file_name}.{file_extension[1:]}" 
            file_client = directory_client.get_file_client(filename)
            with open(os.path.join(local_path, filename), "rb") as local_file:
                file_client.upload_data(local_file, overwrite=True)

            data = f"{new_filename}\n".encode('utf-8')
            offset = checkpoint_file_client_new.get_file_properties().size
            checkpoint_file_client_new.append_data(data, offset=offset, length=len(data))
            checkpoint_file_client_new.flush_data(offset + len(data))

Output:


I have tried this and I only end up with one filename written to the file in the cloud. I wish all of them to be written to the file since I have multiple files.

Updated answer, Hope it address your issue.

It works! Thanks so much! Do you mind explaining this part a bit so I get better understanding?

The code checks if each item in the local directory is a file, then extracts its name and extension.It uploads each file to Azure Storage, overwriting existing ones if needed.Finally, it appends the uploaded filenames to a checkpoint file, ensuring data integrity.
